# How to integrate my macros in ProTEXT

Tags: xetex, miktex, plain-tex

I installed ProTEXT from the TeXLive 2017 CD on a Windows 10 system  and am using TeXWorks. I use plain TeX coding and the XeTeX format. I have it working except that I have to include my macros and images  in the same directory as the source file I am working on in order for XeTeX to find them---obviously not acceptable.

First question: what is the minimum structure I would need for TDS compliance? Ie., what goes after `\texmf-local\` for the plain-TeX macros (targets of `\input`)  and what goes after `\texmf-local\` for the XeTeX-readable image files (targets of `\XeTeXpicfile`)?

Second question: what comes BEFORE the `\texmf-local\` on my system? How can I find out?

I found a MikTeX Settings utility that lets me identify the location of registered root directories and let me add to them. But I am not sure what to add there, or if that is the appropriate way to do it.

Thank you for helping a beginner with startup problems.
 
George

Comment: Do you mind showcasing some code of what you are doing now (or what you expect to do)?

Comment: You wrote before:
I just installed TeX Live 2017 and am using XeTeX,
Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.99998 (MiKTeX 2.9.6300 64-bit)
(preloaded format=xetex 2018.12.4) 4 DEC 2018 22:30.
TeX Live and MiKTeX are different distributions.
Are you really using TeX Live?

Comment: @AkiraKakuto well I installed MikTeX and TeXWorks. So I think what I have is the ProTEXT package. Assuming that is the case, how would I get those macros integrated?

Comment: @AlexRecuenco i have been using plain TeX since about 1996 to generate legal pleadings. My macro file is based on manual.tex from The TeXBook. Until recently I used a commercial package called PCTeX but it isn’t keeping up with all the new developments. So I want to switch over to the packages from TUG.  I have been a TUG member since about 1996. But not a TeXpert obviously!

Comment: GAS4: Please wait for an answer by a MiKTeX user.

Comment: If you really have miktex installed, put your plain macros in a folder (outside miktex) `whatever/mytexmf/tex/generic/GAS4` and then run on a command line `initexmf --register-root=whatever/mytexmf` ("whatever" should be some sensible begin of a path like `C:\somefolder`, `mytexmf` can also have another name.) I do not really recommend to use an miktex from 2017. A lot things changed in the last year, and getting package updates can be difficult with it.